# HLS Metadata ID3 tag not working

Tags: ios, swift, metadata, http-live-streaming, id3

I have a list of audio URLs in a TableView, so every time I tapped on each cell on `didSelectRowAt` this method will be called

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // Prepare Audio URL
    let audioUrl = URL(string: (channelSelected.audioUrl?.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlFragmentAllowed))!)
    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: audioUrl!)
    playerItem.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "timedMetadata", options: .new, context: nil)
    player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
    playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
    playerViewController.player = player
    present(playerViewController, animated: true, completion: {
        self.playerViewController.player?.play()
    })
}
```

And based on the tutorials, I implemented observe value listener

```
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    print("keypath = \(keyPath!)")
    let avPlayerItem: AVPlayerItem = object as! AVPlayerItem
    if let timedMetadata = avPlayerItem.timedMetadata {
        print("Timed metadata = \(timedMetadata)")
    } else {
        print("Timed metadata nil")
    }
}
```

The problem is that `timedMetadata` is always nil. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: please give me audio URL, It may not be supported metadata
Try this sound it works
http://ice1.somafm.com/groovesalad-128-mp3

Comment: @a.masri can I pm you the audio URL?

Comment: yes try this url  http://ice1.somafm.com/groovesalad-128-mp3

Comment: @a.masri what is the complete url? It is not playing on my end. Is this correct? URL(string: "http://ice1.somafm.com/groovesalad-128-mp3.m3u8")!

Comment: ok try this ur1 : https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-player/demos/basic/audio-metadata/assets/index.m3u8


url 2 :  http://ice1.somafm.com/groovesalad-128-mp3

just add http:// first url

Comment: your url  not be supported metadata this is server issue :)

Comment: this `URL(string: "http://ice1.somafm.com/groovesalad-128-mp3")`

Comment: Yes the jwplayer URL is now working. And I get the metadata, so this is a server issue.

Comment: @a.masri may I know what streaming server are you using? Are you familiar with Wowza?

Comment: yes  this is a server issue :)

Comment: It has nothing to do with the Player or server  but it is a problem in meta data tags 
read this document 

https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-player/demos/basic/audio-metadata/assets/index.m3u8

Comment: @a.masri thanks for clarifying. I have little experience on this. Can you answer so I can accept

Comment: using this tool https://www.mp3tag.de/en/  you can edit audio file add meta data tags and  upload to server

Comment: @a.masri Thanks! Can you add that as an answer so I can accept thanks!

Comment: i added my answer :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your code works fine, the reason of this problem is caused by an issue from the server side.

You can use this tool [mp3tag](https://www.mp3tag.de/en/) to edit the audio file - add meta data tags and upload it to server.

As examples, you can try these audios included metadata tags:

> http://ice1.somafm.com/groovesalad-128-mp3
>
> https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-player/demos/basic/audio-metadata/assets/index.m3u8

To confirm, the above files should work fine with your code.

Answer (score 3):

This is another alternative because I found out the server was not using "timed metadata". Here is how we implemented on our end, for those who haven't found an answer. The backend is using Wowza Server.

```
let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: audioUrl!)
let adID = AVMetadataItem.identifier(forKey: "X-TITLE", keySpace: .hlsDateRange)
let metadataCollector = AVPlayerItemMetadataCollector(identifiers: [adID!.rawValue], classifyingLabels: nil)
        metadataCollector.setDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
playerItem.add(metadataCollector)
```

and then declare an extension of `AVPlayerItemMetadataCollectorPushDelegate`

```
    func metadataCollector(_ metadataCollector: AVPlayerItemMetadataCollector, didCollect metadataGroups: [AVDateRangeMetadataGroup], indexesOfNewGroups: IndexSet, indexesOfModifiedGroups: IndexSet) {
             for metadataGroup in metadataGroups {
                     for metadata in metadataGroup.items {
             }
                     }
    }
```