# Swift - AVPlayer load failed with error Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled"

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, audiotoolbox

I try to play a video from url string. But I have get some error as question title.

I try this code in below. videoPath is a url string.

```
let videoURL = URL(string: videoPath)
        let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL!)
        let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
        playerViewController.player = player
        self.present(playerViewController, animated: true) {
            playerViewController.player!.play()
        }
```

**Below is error log :**

> load failed with error Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999
>   "cancelled" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://b...a.mp4,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://b...a.mp4,
>   _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
>       "LocalDataTask <841B2FFA-479B-4E5A-9BD3-D9207EAA0D32>.<2>" ), _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <841B2FFA-479B-4E5A-9BD3-D9207EAA0D32>.<2>,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=cancelled} [-999]

I set the info.plist --

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>www.example.com</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                <string>TLSv1.1</string>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

**NOTE:** The problem is occured with 10 minutes longer videos. Is it a normal ?

Comment: Can you please share If videURL returns a valid url?

Comment: It is vaild. When you try to open with browser this url . The video is shown and played

Comment: can you say what fixed it?

Comment: I started getting this when started to use urlAsset.resourceLoader.preloadsEligibleContentKeys = true with streaming CMAF playlist. However i realized it only occurred on SIMULATOR, not device. For me it had nothing to do with AVPlayer as this was happening on a screen that didn't even instantiate a movie player yet.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to present the `AVPlayerViewController` inside `viewDidLoad`? If so you could try presenting it after the view controller's view is added to the window hierarchy - `viewDidAppear` for example. Keep in mind that `viewDidAppear` will be called when you navigate back to the controller and the modal presentation will be triggered again.

Comment: It's in viewDidAppear

Answer (score 0):

Does the URL require cookies to be set ? I faced the same issue with missing cookies.
You can check by trying to open the url in an incognito-window. If it still plays fine then perhaps you can debug this by -

Creating an `AVURLAsset` object with the URL eg -
`AVURLAsset(url: <URL>, options:[])` and set the `resourceLoader` delegate to self. 
Like `urlAsset?.resourceLoader.setDelegate(self, queue: .main)`
 and implement the functions

```
func resourceLoader(_ resourceLoader: AVAssetResourceLoader, shouldWaitForLoadingOfRequestedResource loadingRequest: AVAssetResourceLoadingRequest) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func resourceLoader(_ resourceLoader: AVAssetResourceLoader, shouldWaitForRenewalOfRequestedResource renewalRequest: AVAssetResourceRenewalRequest) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func resourceLoader(_ resourceLoader: AVAssetResourceLoader, didCancel loadingRequest: AVAssetResourceLoadingRequest) {

}

func resourceLoader(_ resourceLoader: AVAssetResourceLoader, shouldWaitForResponseTo authenticationChallenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func resourceLoader(_ resourceLoader: AVAssetResourceLoader, didCancel authenticationChallenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge) {

}
```

But if it does require cookies - Set them in the `AVURLAsset` object eg 

 `let asset = AVURLAsset(url: videoURL, options: ["AVURLAssetHTTPHeaderFieldsKey": ["Cookie": "<YOUR TOKEN>"]])`

Answer (score 0):

The reason could be wrong metadata in the video. Take a look at this thread which I answered: [AVPlayer HLS live stream IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50020778/avplayer-hls-live-stream-ios/54322588#54322588)

The transcoded video needs to have `profile baseline` in order to be played in AVPlayer. Take look at the ffmpeg transcoding command for details:

https://gist.github.com/chung-nguyen/d88e73e3cc8788878f5ffb8c232b4729

Answer (score 0):

NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://b...a.mp4
The url with "http" prefix always fails irrespective of what ATS you have.
please visit my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60036145/6681300)